# Basic Behaviour of Arrays and Pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

```
#line 1----int nums[7] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
#line 2----int *n = &nums[3];
#line 3----printf("n[0]=%d n[1]=%d n[2]=%d \n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);
```

Output:

> n[0]=8 n[1]=9 n[2]=10

**First Question:**

An Array is a LinkedList in C, is that why the values in line 2, that are printed in line 3, also include the values of nums[4], nums[5]...and so on (which are 8,9,10...etc)?

**Second Question:**

Why is there a "&" sign in line #2? If I create a variable and print it out, without using the & sign, it prints out normally, eg:

```
int *x = 50;
printf("X: %d",x) // prints out 50
```

but if I do:

```
int *x = 50;
printf("X: %d", &x) // prints out 684958....some long number
```

Yet when it is an array, in the example above:

```
#line 2----int *n = nums[3]; // I removed the & from &nums[3]

#line 3----printf("n[0]=%d n[1]=%d n[2]=%d \n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);
```

The program crashes.

Why is there a difference here?

Comment: **An Array is a LinkedList in C** no it isn't. It's a linear sequence of memory.

Comment: Did you lookup what the unary operator `&` actually does?  You can't go adding and removing random characters from a program and expect it to behave.  In C that can lead you to wrong conclusions since there is so much *undefined behaviour*.  You must read a book and follow a tutorial, C is a small language to learn but you must learn the techniques and culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Question:** *An Array is a LinkedList in C ?* No, an array and a linkedList both are different. A `LinkedList`(collection of similar/different-2 data types) can have `array`(collection of similar data types) as a part of it but both are not same.

```
int nums[7] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
```

here `nums` is an array of 7 integers and all elements are stored in **consecutive** memory location & array name represents its base address. Lets assume `nums` starting address is `0x100` then it looks like

```
  nums[0]   nums[1]    nums[2]     nums[3]   nums[4]   nums[5]   nums[6]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    5    |     6     |     7     |    8    |    9    |  10    |  11    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x100     0x104       0x108       0x112     0x116     0x120    0x124
nums
LSB
```

Next when the statement `int *n = &nums[3];` executed where `n` is integer pointer and its pointing to `&nums[3]` i.e `0x112` as shown in above. So for `n` `n[0]` is `0x112` not `0x100` and if you increments `n` it increments by 4 bytes & so on.

```
    -----------
   |   0x112  |   <--- int *n = &nums[3]; /* n is pointer and it needs address and here & is unary operator and &num[3] is assigned to n */
    ----------
   n
```

And

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|    5    |     6     |     7     |    8    |    9    |  10    |  11 |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
0x100     0x104       0x108      0x112     0x116     0x120    0x124
                                  |         |         |        |
                                  n[0]      n[1]      n[2]     n[3]
```

From your question, the code block

```
int *n = nums[3]; // I removed the & from &nums[3]
printf("n[0]=%d n[1]=%d n[2]=%d \n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);
```

here `n` points to `8` and its not a valid address, it looks like

```
   ---------
   |   8    | <-- not that n is int pointer
   ---------
  n
```

And when you try to print `n[0]` it crashes because you are trying to print the value at address `8` which is invalid address, address `8` may be reserved for some other purpose, not for your executable `a.out`.

```
n[0] = *(n + 0)
     = *(8) = you are dereferencing invalid address which causes crash
```

Also

```
    int *x = 50;
    printf("X: %d",x) // it prints what X holds and that is 50 
    printf("X: %d", &x); /* &X means address of X, its an address not some long number , also use %p format specifier to print address. */
    printf("X: %d", *x); /* this will cause crashes, as X points to invalid address
```

Here `x` is an integer pointer & it should initialize with valid address like

```
int var = 50;
int *x = &var; /* now x points to valid address */
printf(" value at the address : %d\n",*x);/* prints 50 */
```

And finally my suggestion is that read a good `C` book & understand array & pointers chapters very well.

Comment: Upvote: best answer you can give to a newbie. Good to point out that a book helps. Such a basic is part of every tutorial on  C and is not really a question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question.

Arrays are not like linked lists. Elements of an array are stored in memory in a row, while elements of a linked list are scattered in memory. This means if you know the address of a first element in an array, then you can access the second element of an array by adding 1 to the address of a first element, because they are stored one after another. You can not do this with a list because elements of a list are all over the memory, and in one element of a list you must have a pointer to another memory location where the second element is stored.

Now this line of code

```
 int *n = &nums[3];
```

- int * means that variable n is a pointer to a memory address
- &nums[3] is giving the address in memory of the third element in an array nums

So after that line of code, in variable n you have a memory location of a third element of array nums. Because elements are stored one after another in programing language c, you can access a fourth element of nums by adding 1 to the value of n. This is why your printf function

```
printf("n[0]=%d n[1]=%d n[2]=%d \n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);
```

is printing 9 10 and 11.

&nums == &nums[0] <==> memory address of an element 5

&nums[3] <==> memory address that of an element 9, because it is 3 places after 5

Second answer

The sign "&" in line 2 is giving you the memory location where is stored element nums[3].

In this line of code

```
int *x = 50;
```

You are saying that x is pointing to memory address 50. That is why you get 50 as a result of printf function like this

```
printf("%d\n",x);
```

But when there is symbol "&"  prefix to x, then you are printing the value that is stored on memory address 50

```
printf("%d\n",&x);
```

Thats why the output is some number 60435...

The last thing you asked is why your program is crashing after these two lines, when you remove prefix & of variable nums[3]

```
 int *n = nums[3]
 printf("n[0]=%d n[1]=%d n[2]=%d \n", n[0], n[1], n[2]);
```

It is because now variable n is pointing to memory address 8==nums[3], and  you probably can not access that memory and thats why it crashes.

Remember int *n= &nums[3] is pointing to the memory address of nums[3], but when you type just int *n=nums[3] than it is poitning to memory address 8 because 8 is the value that is stored in nums[3]

Comment: Not adding one to address. This is wrong. Adding one to the pointer of the array elements type.